# Dynamically resize div on asp.net Page with CSS

Tags: css, html, resize

I have a site that uses a master page which all the pages inherit from. The master page uses a style sheet for layout and feel.  The basic Layout is this

```
<html>
<body >
<form runat="server" >
<div class="page" >
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
        </div>           
        <div class="main">            
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">                 
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</form>
```

My issue is I would like the main div to re size based on the clients window size
in the Css for .page I have the width set to 85% and this works fine, but when I try to set the height to a percentage it only is the height of the content are of the screen that is loaded.  If I set it to a pixel value it will show the the height proper to that setting but I would like it to grow and shrink based on the client window.

I have search around and tried the min-height setting and other things I have found through goggle but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the height with jQuery or javascript.

```
var browser_height = $(window).height();

$('.main').css({'height':browser_height});
```